# CollectionView not displaying the correct data in the cells

Tags: swift

When I scroll through the collectionView, the data displayed is incorrect and also changes when scrolling up and down. I have implemented the function prepareForReuse in the collection view cell

The data in my arrays are correct, and the data inside

> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt
> indexPath: IndexPath)

is correct as well when I log it.

**Collection View Cell**

```
class ToonCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var toonTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var toonImage: UIButton!
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        toonTitle.text = nil
        toonImage.imageView!.image = nil
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
}
```

**Table View Cell**

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ToonCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!

    @objc func reloadTableViewData() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTableViewData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadData"), object: nil)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}

extension HomePage: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dateArr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "toonTitle") as? toonTitle else {
            fatalError("Cannot create cell")
        }
        
        cell.date.text = dateArr[indexPath.row]
     
        if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Monday") {
           // cell.identi = "123"
            cell.collectionView.tag = 11
        }
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Tuesday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 22
        }
        
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Wednesday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 33
        }
        
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Thursday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 44
        }
        
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Friday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 55
        }
        
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Saturday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 66
        }
        
        else if(dateArr[indexPath.row] == "Sunday") {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 77
        }
        else {
            cell.collectionView.tag = 1
        }
      
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }
    
}

extension ToonCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
      //  print("Tag: ", collectionView)
        if(subscribedToons.isEmpty) {
            return 0
        }

        if(collectionView.tag == 11) {
           // print("Monday: ",subscribedToons["Monday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Monday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 22) {
           // print("Tues: ",subscribedToons["Tuesday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Tuesday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 33) {
            //print("Wed: ",subscribedToons["Wednesday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Wednesday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 44) {
           // print("Thurs: ",subscribedToons["Thursday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Thursday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 55) {
           // print("Fri: ",subscribedToons["Friday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Friday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 66){
            //print("Sat: ",subscribedToons["Saturday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Saturday"]!.count
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 77){
           // print("TEST COUNT: ",subscribedToons["Sunday"]!.count)
            //print("Sun: ",subscribedToons["Sunday"]!.count)
            return subscribedToons["Sunday"]!.count
        }
        
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ToonCollectionCell
        let collectionIndex = collectionView.tag
        
        var day = ""
        
        if(collectionView.tag == 11) {
            day = "Monday"
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 22) {
           day = "Tuesday"
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 33) {
           day = "Wednesday"
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 44) {
            day = "Thursday"
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 55) {
            day = "Friday"
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 66) {
            day = "Saturday"
            
        }
        else if(collectionView.tag == 77) {
            day = "Sunday"
        }
        
        if(subscribedToons[day]!.count == 0) {
            print("COUNT IS 0")
        }
        
        cell.toonImage?.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.toonImage?.subviews.first?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        cell.toonTitle.text = subscribedToons[day]![indexPath.row]["title"] as! String
        var toonId = subscribedToons[day]![indexPath.row]["toonId"] as! String
            
        var url = "urlexample" + toonId + "?alt=media&token="
        cell.toonImage?.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: url)!, for: .normal)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        return cell
        
        
    }
    
}
```

**HomePage View Controller**

```
class HomePage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var exitSearch: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorColor = .clear
        searchBar.addPadding(.left(20))
        searchBar.addPadding(.right(40))
        exitSearch.isHidden = true
        let currentDate = Date()
        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        
        for i in 0...6 { // Appends the following days to dateArr
            dateComponent.day = i
            let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: currentDate)
            let index = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: futureDate!)
            let appendWeekday = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[index-1]
            dateArr.append(appendWeekday)
        }
        print(dateArr)
    }

    @IBAction func exitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        exitSearch.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        exitSearch.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        exitSearch.isHidden = true
    }
    
   

}
```

Comment: When you say the wrong data is displayed, could you elaborate what is wrong / what is currently showing and what you expect it to show ?

Comment: The data that is displayed in the collectionview cells are the wrong items in my array, and the data also changes when I scroll up and down

Comment: I see you have two bits of information, the `toonImage` and `toonTitle`, do both display the wrong data or just one of them ?

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is with the asynchronous loading of the background image. Ensure you clear the background image right after obtaining the cell from the collection view reusable pool

Comment: The toonImage and toonTitle match each other, but the data displayed is wrong. When I remove the image fetch, it still shows the wrong Label data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

I had to add these lines of code into my ToonCell file

```
@objc func reloadTableViewData() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func resetCollectionView() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        resetCollectionView()
    }
```